# Resolving problems in XCode 7 crash reporter

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I recently released the 2.0 version of my app. https://itunes.apple.com/app/neo-virtual-reality-for-reddit/id1013650716

I have users reporting that the app crashes but I can't figure out what to do in XCode. When I open a crash in the project it does not show me anything where the crash occured. See the screenshot attached for more information:

[image: XCode crash reporter screenshot]

How can I solve my crashes in the future?

Edit: Bitcode is enabled and app symbols are included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do enable the Bitcode and having this issue, simply click the **"
[Download dSYMs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CLHp.png)"** button in the Organizer and try again.

Refer to the [Apple Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html),

> Because the final compilation of your binary occurs on the App Store, your Mac will not contain the debug symbol (dSYM) files needed to symbolicate crash reports received from App Review or from users who have sent you crash reports from their devices. Although a dSYM file is produced when you archive your application, it is for the bitcode binary and can not be used to symbolicate crash reports. The App Store makes the dSYM files generated during bitcode compilation available for you to download, from Xcode or from the iTunes Connect website. **You must download these dSYM files in order to symbolicate crash reports received from App Review or from users who have sent you crash reports from their devices.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to symbolicate the crash report:

1. Download the crash report from iTunes Connect
2. Open the Devices window in XCode:

[image]

3. Connect an iOS device
4. Choose View Device Logs:

[image]

5. Drag the report from Finder to the left section
6. See a more detailed error message

[image]

This works only, if you have the archived project still available (you can check this in your Organizer window

Comment: Where in itunes connect can I download the crash reports?

Comment: Ok I found them in the finder by clicking show in finder in the crash reporter but I can't drag the file on my device.. I still have the archive

Comment: Where is the crash report you showed in your screenshot from?

Comment: I have updated my description. I've forgotten something in the first version

Comment: Have you clicked on "View Device Logs"? In the new screen drag the report to the left part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104068/discussion-between-nick-st-and-stefan).

Comment: If you have an .xccrashpoint file: Right click on it and select "Show Package Contents". Navigate the folder structure to find the actual .crash file. Copy this file to somewhere else and follow the steps from my answer.

Comment: Can you upload a new screenshot with the error from the crash log?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: disable BitCode when uploading the archive to iTunes Connect