# Xcode crash reporter and bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, crash-reports

My main app binary is not symbolicated correctly. But I see symbols from frameworks built with help of CocoaPods.

It is the same problem as described in this question:
[Resolving problems in XCode 7 crash reporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529612/resolving-problems-in-xcode-7-crash-reporter)

But answers for this question is not resolve an issue absolutely. 
It's crazy to re-symbolicate reports every time manually. 
And it's not really forward-looking idea to turn off bit code.

I fill the problem is somewhere in project configuration. Looks like CocoaPods do this the right way but I can't find suitable configuration for my app.

Do anybody know solution that solves problem fully once and forever?

[image]

Here the same project crash with bitcode turned off:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving problems in XCode 7 crash reporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529612/resolving-problems-in-xcode-7-crash-reporter)